# Mac OSX Sierra 10.12.2 Ruby Installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, macos-sierra

I am having difficulty installing Ruby on Mac OsX Sierra 10.12.2

Have been following directions according to www.installrails.com

1) Having correctly installed XCode, 2) making sure Command line Works, 3) installed, configured and verified Homebrew (1.1.7), 4) installed and verified Git, 5) installed and verified RVM, I then try and install Ruby 2.3.3 (using the command rvm use ruby --install --default).

However, the installation continually fails with the following error/log:

```
    Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake openssl',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/JRD/.rvm/log/1484256081_ruby-2.3.3/package_install_automake_openssl.log
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 1 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation\n'
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
++ case "$_system_version" in
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-2.3.3 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

Very frustrating.  Have looked for multiple solutions online and cannot find applicable resolution.  Have also tried other StackOverflow answers and none adequately seems to address issue with the latest versions/Sierra OSX that I'm using.  Also, the suggested "brew repair" and "brew doctor" commands do not resolve it.

Can someone please explain error and suggest solution?

It would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Does `brew install openssl` work by itself?

Comment: Actually, it does not.  When I use that command, installation fails with the following error: Error: You must `brew link pkg-config` before openssl can be installed.  And, when I try to use the 'brew link pkg-config', that also fails with the following error:Linking /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.1_2... 
Error: Could not symlink .
/usr/local/opt is not writable

Comment: Sounds like you found your issue then. Make `/usr/local/opt` writeable. If you need help, do a `stat /usr/local/opt` and share the permission bits.

Comment: That works.  Thank you!

Comment: FYI you can write an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted, if @coreyward doesn't want to.